# Only allow editable = true on specific events in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to get a FullCalendar to only allow `event Resize` if two specific ids match, but I can't get it to work.

Essentially, I'm loading FullCalendar within a component. This component has a unique ID represented as an event on the calendar. Once the calendar loads to the page, how can I make sure to only set `editable: true` to that specific event? See below in `eventRender` for my pseudo code of what I wish to achieve

```
loadDataToCalendar: function(component, salesAppointments, resExceptions) {
    let myEventid;
    var ele = component.find('calendar').getElement();
    $(ele).fullCalendar({
        eventResize: function(event) {
            component.set("v.startTime", event.start._d);
            component.set("v.endTime", event.end._d);
            component.set("v.showSaveButton", true)
        },
        eventRender: function(event) {
            if (event.id === myUniqueIdHere) {
                event.editable = true // this is what I'm trying to achieve
            }
        },

        header: {
            left: 'prev, next, today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        },

        eventOverlap: false,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventSources: [salesAppointments, resExceptions],
        timezone: 'local',
    });
},
```

So by default, I want `editable` to be false. When the calendar renders and has a matching ID, I need to set that specific event to editable: true. How would I achieve this? I've tried using `eventRender` without 
 success.

Comment: The text and title say this is about 'editable', though the first line is confusing... "I'm trying to get a FullCalendar to only allow event Resize" - should be 'editable'??

Comment: `eventResize` is the function in FullCalendar that allows you to drag an event and make it longer/shorter

Comment: Yes, though all the rest of the question (including the 'if') is about 'editable', which is about modifying the event data.....  If you really meant you only want it to resize with a certain ID, then you should change your question to show your code on what you are trying there that pertains to the ID.  In most cases, though, I believe my answer is the direction you should go.  If not, please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the compare on the server side of where you are generating the event.

Fullcalendar (and most all such programs) can't change things 'on the fly' as you are trying to do - you often will have to set things on the server first and these programs can render, etc. as per the settings you give.

So, in your event, you should set editable = true for the one(s) you want. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

You can't (well, not easily - there might be a very round-about way but I don't think it worthy of trying) do this in the 'render' but is simple if you do the check on the server side.

When I say 'server side', I mean 'the data coming into fullcalendar'.  As you have these in "salesAppointments" and "resExceptions", you may be able to manipulate this a bit in javascript - but, again, not in the fullcalendar section - something like:

```
 loadDataToCalendar: function(component, salesAppointments, resExceptions) {
    let myEventid;
    $(salesAppointments).each(function(event)){
        if (event.id === myUniqueIdHere) {
            event.editable = true;
        }    
    }
    $(resExceptions).each(function(event)){
        if (event.id === myUniqueIdHere) {
            event.editable = true;
        }    
    }
    var ele = component.find('calendar').getElement();
        $(ele).fullCalendar({
            eventResize: function(event) {
                component.set("v.startTime", event.start._d);
                component.set("v.endTime", event.end._d);
                component.set("v.showSaveButton", true)
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next, today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        },
        eventOverlap: false,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventSources: [salesAppointments, resExceptions],
        timezone: 'local',
    });
},
```

Comment: @Stnfordly - I'm not sure what you are asking.  If you have another question, please open it directly and show the code you are using and point out the trouble you are having - SO is built on helping others fix their code - not writing code for you.  Perhaps if you are more clear on what you need help with on this solution someone can also help.  But "provide the working solution..." sounds like "write code for me", which I'm happy to do, but my contract with clients forces me to charge for that.  If you need help, show your code as a question or be more clear on where you are having trouble.